# Prism with WCF services - are they always async?

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, prism

I have started to build a WPF application in MVVM architecture (using Prism infrastructure).

I need the WPF application to connect to several different WCF services.

I am a bit puzzled, because I could not find any samples of such behavior on the net.

I have found some Silverlight+Prism samples that connect to WCF services, but they **always** do so asynchronously.

Is there a reason for this ? (my services are all 'sync').

Comment: I don't think there's any samples from the developers where a WPF app connects to a service; only Silverlight examples...and as pointed out below, Silverlight can only connect async to services. I've used some PRISM components in a WPF app that is a client for a WCF service, so it's possible.

Comment: have you got any online samples you looked at that I can use ? I am struggling with understanding where exactly I perform the 'openning' of the channel, where I use it, how I use it (new instance every time the ViewModel is opened, or a singleton - how will this affect a faulted channel) etc...

Comment: I don't...but you can follow the pattern used in the StockTraderRI app. In there, you can see they're using the concept of a Controller (check out the [PRISM docs](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/55580)). If you're using MEF, you can control how the "part" (i.e. the controller) is created (shared or non-shared), so you can end up with a singleton controller that holds your service reference. The StockTrader app is pretty advanced, so I'd start with the documentation and follow along there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight only supports async WCF calls so that is why all those samples do it that way.

There's nothing in Prism that prevents you from making synchronous WCF calls but you will not be able to multi-target those modules for Silverlight. In terms of UI (even in WPF) you're probably better off making those calls asynchronously.

Whether you have implemented your services sync or async is not really relevant to the client anyway - when generating your client proxy you can generate async Begin/End pairs for each operation.